# How to make IntelliJ bottom Bar thinnner

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, resize

I am using both community and ultimate IntelliJ at home, and it looks like this:[image]

This is my private IntelliJ ultimate with bottom bar taking 40% spaces.
This is also my community version, which looks the way I want.
[image]

Community intelliJ has strong left and right side which gives little to bottom part. - this stuff with terminal and other boring stuff. Bring upon me a knowledge please, upon which, I could make my IntelliJ behave like his little community version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to *File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance* and enable *Widescreen tool window layout* under *Tool Windows* section.

[image: Widescreen tool window layout option under preferences]